# Where can I see my highest spree?

Tags: diablo-iii

When getting a Destruction, Mighty Blow, Massacre or Pulverized it will show how many targets it effected and say if it is a new record for you. Is there a place where I can see what my current records for each are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only stat tracking that is available currently, is what is shown in your profile.

You can access someone else's (Or your own) profile by right clicking on their name or portrait and clicking "View Profile" - At the window appearing in the top left corner, is the stats mentioned.

The stats shown track

- Achievement Points
- Total Elite Kills
- Total Gold Gathered
- Highest Hardcore Level
- Lifetime Kills

(Note that these stats are not specific for each character, but rather account-wide, spanning all your Hero Characters on the specific server you are currently on.)